# Why when a character array is compared to another character array, output is wrong but when character array is compared to a string output is correct?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, if-statement, data-structures

Question - The translation from the Berland language into the Birland language is not an easy task. Those languages are very similar: a berlandish word differs from a birlandish word with the same meaning a little: it is spelled (and pronounced) reversely. For example, a Berlandish word code corresponds to a Birlandish word edoc. However, it's easy to make a mistake during the «translation». Vasya translated word s from Berlandish into Birlandish as t. Help him: find out if he translated the word correctly.

Input -
The first line contains word s, the second line contains word t. The words consist of lowercase Latin letters. The input data do not consist unnecessary spaces. The words are not empty and their lengths do not exceed 100 symbols.

Output -
If the word t is a word s, written reversely, print YES, otherwise print NO.

When I write this code, the output is wrong -

```
int main(){
    char s[100000],a[100000];
    cin >> s >> a;
    strrev(s);
    if(s==a){
        cout << "YES";
    }else{cout << "NO";}
}
```

But when I write this code, the output is correct -

```
int main(){
    char s[100000];
    string a;
    cin >> s >> a;
    strrev(s);
    if(s==a){
        cout << "YES";
    }else{cout << "NO";}
}
```

Why is it like this, is there a rule that a character array cannot be compared to another character array and if so, how can it be compared to a string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember that arrays naturally *decay* to pointers to their first elements, and it's such pointers that you are comparing.

In short, what you're really doing is:

```
if(&s[0] == &a[0])
```

And those two pointers will *never* be equal.

To compare the *contents* of character arrays, you need to use `strcmp()` or similar function instead, eg:

```
if(strcmp(s, a) == 0)
```

Since you're programming in C++, please use `std::string` for all your strings. There are overloads for the `==` operator that do the right thing if you have `std::string` values.